# How can I remove superfluous parameters from SpecFlow step method when using step argument transformation?

Tags: c#, specflow

I converted a SpecFlow step to depend on `StepArgumentTransformation` so I would not have to deal with multiple primitive parameters, but could use a single complex parameter, built by a transformation method.

But I learned that I could not remove the primitive parameters from the step, because that would result in a "parameter count mismatch" exception.

```
[Given("(something (\d) (\d))")]
public void Step(Something something)
{
    // Does not work (parameter count mismatch)
}

[Given("(something (\d) (\d))")]
public void Step(Something something, int x, int y)
{
    // Works, but is slightly confusing due to unused parameters
}

[StepArgumentTransformation("something (\d) (\d)")]
public Something Transform(int x, int y)
{
    var something = new Something(x, y);
    return something;
}
```

How can I get rid of the `x` and `y` parameters in the step method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adapt the regex of the binding.

Here is a concrete example:

```
[Given("the coordinates are '(.*)'")]
public void Step(Something something)
{
    // Does not work (parameter count mismatch)
}

[StepArgumentTransformation("X:(\d)/Y:(\d)")]
public Something Transform(int x, int y)
{
    var something = new Something(x, y);
    return something;
}

Usage:

Scenario: coordinate system

    Given the coordinates are 'X:1/Y:2'
```

You can find an example here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/SpecFlow.Examples.StepArgumentTransformation

The documentation for Step Argument Transformation is here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Argument-Conversions/

Comment: Cool, thanks! Indeed the parentheses are used by SpecFlow and playing around with them seems to have done the trick: `(something \d \d)` is interpreted as mapping to a single argument (notice only one pair of parentheses), and SpecFlow uses the transformation to provide the value for that argument.